# angular 2 ngFor Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I have a nested object with data that I am trying to access with ngFor. 
I am able to reach the first part of the data with the first ngFor (app_name, time_stamp etc)

But for some reason I am not getting to the nested object of test_cases. When I try it breaks the whole page and the console keeps telling me "Cannot read property 'test_cases' of undefined" and I can't seem to figure out why...

(first part of) data inside the component:

```
    export class AppComponent {
        tests = TESTS;

        var TESTS: Test[] = [
            {
                "app_name": "website",
                "time_stamp": "2018-01-20T12:00:00Z",
                "test_cases": [
                    {
                        "test_name": "View article",
                        "status": true,
                     }]
         }]
```

HTML partial:

```
<div id="tested-app" *ngFor = "let item of tests">
    <h2>----<span> {{ item.app_name }} </span>----</h2>
    <p id="time"> Time: <span> {{item.time_stamp}} </span> </p>
</div>
<div class="module" *ngFor="let subItem of item.test_cases">
    <h3>{{subItem.test_name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put your second `ngFor` inside the first one.

Comment: item seems to be scoped to the first div. If you move the second div inside the first one it should work(even if it's not exactly the output you expect)

Comment: Show us how your model Test looks like

Comment: I found it! There was still was a typo hiding... :) so basically yes, I moved the second div inside the first div and that solved it, thanks!!

Any idea how I can vote your answer up @AndresM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For peeps who are struggling with this:

John Montgomery and Andres M answered this in the comments, I had to put the second div inside the first.